# WordPress Theme Directory Issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I have installed a new WordPress theme and activated it and it's all loaded correctly but there's one issue. My websites are stored in a development location which looks like this:

```
www.domain.com/websitename1/
www.domain.com/websitename2/
```

On my old theme I used to be able to put paths to images like this and it used to load the image with no problems:

```
<img src="/assets/images/image1.jpg" />
```

However, when I do this on this theme, instead the file path goes further back to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) rather than where the actual WordPress installation is [www.domain.com/dev/](http://www.domain.com/dev/)

I could use echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); before each / like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/image1.jpg" />
```

But this looks untidy and if it's working on my other theme there must be a global way of setting it?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is the correct way of doing this. hardcoding the URI in your theme files is never a good idea. your old theme was perhaps using relative uri `<img src="assets/images/image1.jpg" />` but this still may break and is not the correct way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct, that's how to do it.

You could use this syntax if you want a shorter version:

```html
<img src="<?=get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/assets/images/image1.jpg" />
```

`<?=...?>` is the same as `<?php echo ... ?>`